# Как конвертировать LocalDate или LocalDateTime в Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar, localdate

Есть ли простой способ получить из объектов класса `LocalDate` или `LocalDateTime` объект класса `Calendar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1-й подход:**

Получим количество секунд прошедших с начала Unix-эпохи. И на основе этого создадим объект `Calendar`.

Для `LocalDate`

```
long epochSec = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(epochSec*1000);
```

Для `LocalDateTime`

```
long epochSec = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(epochSec*1000);
```

**2-й подход:**

У объекта `Calendar` есть метод `set`,  в котором можно задать информацию о времени.

Для `LocalDate`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue() - 1, localDate.getDayOfMonth());
```

Для `LocalDateTime`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(localDateTime.getYear(), localDateTime.getMonthValue() - 1, localDateTime.getDayOfMonth(), localDateTime.getHour(), localDateTime.getMinute(), localDateTime.getSecond());
```

Заметьте, что `LocalDate` и `LocalDateTime` считают месяцы с `1` в то время, как Calendar считает месяцы с `0`. Поэтому при передаче параметров нужно вычитать единицу.

Также в случае с `LocalDateTime` можно не передавать в метод `set` последний параметр (секунды) или вообще обойтись тремя параметрами, как в случае с `LocalDate`.